# Why my ppp modem interface doesn't show me a public IP address

Tags: linux, modem, isp, ppp, pppd

I have a cellular modem from Zoomtel. I connected my BeagleBone embedded computer running Debian to it via pppd.

When I run ifconfig , I see the interface ppp0. However this gets a local IP address in the 10 range : 10.X.X.X .

Now this I don't understand. Shouldn't it be a public IP address here, because the BeagleBone and modem are connected directly to the internet via a service provider and not behind a router.

My understanding was that the ISP (Internet Service Provider) assigns us a dynamic public IP address when we connect. Why don't we see a public IP address and not a private one in the 10 range when we run ifconfig. How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't it be a public IP address here, because the BeagleBone and modem are connected directly to the internet via a service provider and not behind a router.

First, the Internet is *made* out of routers... the distinction you're looking for is "not behind a router **that does NAT**". A home gateway router performs address translation, the service provider's routers usually don't.

But second, as is unfortunately the case with more and more ISPs, your BeagleBone and modem *aren't* directly connected to the Internet anymore. Primarily due to IPv4 address shortage, your ISP now performs NAT *on the service provider's side* as well. (This is called "CGNAT", or carrier-grade NAT.) It's the exact same mechanism, but it usually shares the same public address between multiple customers.

(Indeed IPv4 address shortage is the reason your typical home router has to translate addresses, too – but it wasn't quite as severe previously, and one public IPv4 per customer was still easily doable. Now, however, some ISPs can't even afford that.)

CGNAT is especially common among mobile ISPs, as the vast majority of their customers never have any reason to notice the change, and usually the ISP has at least a reserve of public addresses for the few who do need one.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm kind of new to this stuff. I was expecting the ISP to assign me a public IP address. My ISP has assigned me a class A address in this case : 10.X.X.X , which are reserved for local IP addresses? Now I have the problem of how do I connect to my modem and BeagleBone from the outside world? I would like to SSH into my BeagleBone via the ISP and modem.

Comment: That's been covered in several other threads on this site (search for "CGNAT"). Short answer is that you need to go through some sort of tunnel/VPN service. Or call your ISP and see if they offer a static public IP address as an extra service.